# Nhibernate Linq - fetchmany where many count == 0

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, has-many, take

I have this query:

```
 var query = session.Query<Album>()
                    .FetchMany(x => x.Tracks)
                    .ThenFetchMany(x => x.Indices)
                    .Where(t => t.Tracks.Any(v => v.Indices.Count == 0))
                    .Take(20)
                    .ToList();
```

`Album` has `List` `Track` (hasmany).
`Track` has `List` `Indices` (hasmany).

instead of getting 20 rows, I get 2 rows.
when I saw the result in the profiler, it looks like the `Take` is referring to the `Track` and not the `Album`.
Any Idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

LINQ

```
var filtered =
    from a in session.Query<Album>()
    from t in a.Tracks
    where !t.Indices.Any()
    select a.Id

var results = session.Query<Album>()
     .Where(a => filtered.Contains(a.Id))
     .Take(20)
     .List()
```

QueryOver

```
var results = session.QueryOver<Album>()
     .WhereRestrictionOn(a => a.Id).IsIn(QueryOver.Of<Album>()
         .JoinQueryOver(a => a.Tracks)
             .Where(t => !t.Indices.Any())
         .Select(a => a.Id))
     .Take(20)
     .List()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big Linq to NHibernate expert but I do know there is another way to query NHibernate that might help you out as well. It's called `QueryOver`. It is strongly typed query syntax that uses Linq-like member expressions. Right now `QueryOver` is much more robust in the NHibernate community mainly because it is based on criteria queries (which have been around for quite some time).

If you are interested in learning more about different query languages you should check out this site: [NHibernate: Queries](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/09/nhibernate-queries.html)

I also have a blog where I have an article about different plugins and technologies you can use with NHibernate (including ways to query) - [My Blog](http://jaredmahan.wordpress.com/)

Below should be a close representation of what you might be looking for using query over.

```
Album a = null;
Tracks t = null;
Indices i = null;
var query = session.GetQueryOver(() => a)
    .JoinAlias(() => a.Tracks, () => t)
    .JoinAlias(() => t.Indicies, () => i)
    .Where(() => i.Indices.Count() == 0)
    .Take(20)
    .ToList()
    ;
```

When adding joins to the query you can also specifiy the join type by adding another parameter of type `JoinType` to the method call. 
Ex:

```
.JoinAlias(() => a.Tracks, () => t, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
```

Comment: this queryover query does suffer from the same problem as the OP describes. Take will be applied to the Join and doesn't return 20 Albums but 20 join rows.